# Kendo UI Mobile - "Add to homescreen" issue on iOS devices

Tags: jquery, html, listview, kendo-ui

I have a problem with iOS devices with my mobile web app using Kendo's mobile framework. Here is the issue:

Currently, loading the web app from  the Safari browser is totally fine. Everything operates as expected.

When I add the homepage of my web app as an icon to the homescreen and load the web app from it, the initial page operates as expected. It's a login page. The user logs in, and upon validating credentials, is taken to a dashboard page.

In the dashboard page, there are many local kendo listviews. When I click on a link to load one of these local listviews, the iOS device takes me out of the "app" and loads the browser app and takes me to my initial login page.

Can someone explain what's going on and if there is some resolution I can provide to the user? Do I have to detect app mode from standalone mode? I've read other posts but nothing incorporated kendo mobile.

I am currently using JQuery v1.8.3 and Kendo v2012.3.1413. I am forcing Kendo to render the ios platform in my web app.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Without looking at your code, nobody will be able to help. Please post a JSFiddle of the code or atleast post the code of the link that you are clicking.

Comment: It was a conceptual thing I did not fully understand about iOS devices, app mode, the Kendo framework, and how they all play nice with eachother. Thanks for taking the time to read this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With iOS devices, if a user adds a website shortcut to the Homescreen and launches the website from that icon, the website enters the state "app mode." The moment the URL changes, however, the website is taken out of app mode and to the safari browser, abandoning any previous session within the website during its "app mode" state. This makes sense and I understand more clearly now why Kendo uses hash tags to navigate views (since a server doesn't consider anything after a hashtag as part of the URL), hence you can stay in this "app mode" while having the ability to load external views.

The problem I had was actually 'VB.Net' related. I used 'Response.Redirect(...)' to take my user to the dashboard page upon successful login. This changed the URL, so the moment I clicked anywhere on the dashboard page, I was taken out of "app mode" and to the safari browser.

To solve my problem, I had to use jquery ajax to call a webmethod that basically detects if, upon postback, the login credentials successfully logged the user in. If it did, I would proceed to navigate to my remote view - the dashboard page. So, my "login" page is now my index page for loading all remote views.